# BarChart Update

Tags: multithreading, javafx, bar-chart, auto-update

Now it is another problem that occurred, it seems that the query I'm using only works for the first time but after pressing the next/previous buttons, it is giving me something else !!

Here is the query I used:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= months.length + 1; i++) {
        try {
            String a;
            if (i < 9) {
                a = y + "0" + (i + 1);
            } else {
                a = y + "" + (i + 1);
            }
            System.out.println("Année Courante " + a);
            conn = DBConnection.connect();
            String sql = "select sum(montant_operation) from operations where (select Extract(YEAR_MONTH from date_operation)) = '" + a + "' and typ_operation ='Versement';";
            final ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement(sql).executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(series1.getData().toString());
                series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(months[i], rs.getFloat("sum(montant_operation)")));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

But is there a query that works fine one time and then it gives error.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `BuildData` (by the way, not following Java Naming Conventions, change its name) method you are updating the data of series. In the same method you are adding this series to the chart. By clicking the "next" button, `BuildData` method is invoked where this chart is added again which is unnecessary. Delete the

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {  
    barchart.getData().add(series1);  
});
```

part from the method and add the chart only once in start:

```
...
...
vbox.getChildren().addAll(box, barchart);
barchart.getData().add(series1);
pane.getChildren().add(vbox);
...
...
```

The tested SSCCE:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class BarChartDemo extends Application {

    final String[] months = {"Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Août", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"};
    //Connection conn;
    final CategoryAxis month_axis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis data_axis = new NumberAxis();
    final XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    private final BarChart<String, Number> barchart = new BarChart(month_axis, data_axis);
    private Integer year = 0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        Button btn_next = new Button("NEXT");
        Button btn_previous = new Button("PREVIOUS");
        HBox box = new HBox(50);
        box.getChildren().addAll(btn_previous, btn_next);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        VBox vbox = new VBox(25);
        box.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0));
        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(box, barchart);
        barchart.getData().add(series1);
        pane.getChildren().add(vbox);
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        BuildData(year);
        btn_next.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                year += 1;
                BuildData(year);
            }
        });
        btn_previous.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                year -= 1;
                BuildData(year);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void BuildData(Integer y) {
        series1.setName("Versement");
        month_axis.setLabel("Mois de l'Année");
        month_axis.setStyle("-fx-font-weight:BOLD;" + "-fx-font-size:15");
        data_axis.setLabel("Valeur des Opérations Bancaires");
        data_axis.setStyle("-fx-font-weight:BOLD;" + "-fx-font-size:15");
        series1.getData().clear(); // clear old values
        for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(months[i], i * 10 * (y-2000)));

//            try {
//                String a;
//                if (i < 9) {
//                    a = y + "0" + (i + 1);
//                } else {
//                    a = y + "" + (i + 1);
//                }
//                conn = DBConnection.connect();
//                String sql = "select sum(montant_operation) from operations where (select Extract(YEAR_MONTH from date_operation)) = '" + a + "' and typ_operation ='Versement';";
//                final ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement(sql).executeQuery();
//                if (rs.next()) {
//                    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(months[i], rs.getFloat("sum(montant_operation)")));
//                }
//            } catch (SQLException e) {
//                System.out.println(e);
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, could yu make something so that I can understand yu !!

Comment: @user2351866, I meant move the code line  `barchart.getData().add(series1);` from BuildData method into start method.

Comment: yep, did that but still the same problem !!

Comment: @user2351866, can you try to run your code in JavaFX 2.2.x and/or on Java 6.

Comment: @user2351866, well I tried your code (with my suggestion) on 2.2 and worked without exception. The exception you received is not the one for code you posted. To investigate further, try to update the code in question with the latest one (with my suggestion), try clean and rebuild the project and post your exact JavaFX runtime version.

Comment: could yu show me what yu've written ? I mean the whole thing !!

Comment: Hey @user2351866 don't shout ha :). Use "!!" a little fewer :). What do you mean with "results"? If you are mentioning the data added to the series, it is not important here on the test code, and the added data is not random. As I said in my previous comment, update your question accordingly. Or change my test code by adding your DB querying code and try again.

Comment: For instance, after pressing the next/previous, it does get values but not correct !!

Comment: Sorry but my "!!" are not for shouting ^^, it's just a bad habit of writing ^^
On the other hand, what I meant but random values, is this !!
<img> http://postimg.org/image/9lhbdzvz9/</img>
The image I put is the representation of the 2013 year where normally, it should only have values in "Septembre" and the value should be around 3500 but it is not, so there always this problem of not updating properly ^^

Comment: @user2351866, this is another problem, it maybe with your sql query or kind of. But you are not getting the initial exception in your question anymore, right? So **please** update your question with the latest state.